# Text mining top keywords for each category

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I am new to text mining and have trying to solve this problem using R.

My dataset looks like this:

```
Col 1: Item Description (Text that I need to mine) ||
Col 2: Item category || 
Col 3: Item Sub Category
```

The output I need to get should be somewhat like this:

```
Topic || Keyword 1 || Keyword 2 || Keyword 3   ... Keyword 10

Category A || Fitness || Beauty ........ 

Category B || .....

Sub Category AZ || 

Sub Category AY ||
```

Basically I need to get the top 10 keywords for each category and sub category.

What would be the best way to do it?

I apologize for my lack of knowledge about R. I would also be open to considering using other open source tools to do this operation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please follow [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example-aka-mcve-minimal-complete-and-ver) which helps us to help you.

Comment: Have you looked at the tidytext package?